# New RAM fails in Dell PowerEdge T310

Tags: memory, hardware

I bought some new RAM for a Dell T310 server after consulting the user manual but after removing the old RAM and putting the new RAM in it doesn't boot up (no POST, just fans whirring away).

The system will boot-up with the old RAM and the new RAM works just fine in another server (Dell R420).

I was fairly careful when selecting this RAM after reading the user manual. I'm hoping someone can point me to where I went wrong.

**Old RAM**: 2 x 4 GB 2Rx8 PC3L - 10600E (Samsung P/N M391B5273DH0-YH9). Each stick was installed in the white levered RAM slots of the T310.

**New RAM**: 2 x 8 GB 2Rx4 PC3L - 10600R (Samsung P/N M393B1K70DH0-YH9)

Before purchasing this RAM, I consulted with the [Dell T310 user manual on page 108](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t310_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf#G5.1283957)

From my reading of the manual I understand:

- DDR3 -- *both new and old are DDR3*
- Registered DIMMs (RDIMMS) OR unbuffered ECC DIMMS (UDIMMS) -- *Old RAM was UDIMM, new RAM is RDIMM*
- Single and dual-rank DIMMs can be 1067- or 1333-MHz -- *both are dual ("2R") ranked*
- UDIMM supports single-rank and dual-rank DIMMs. Only RDIMM supports quad-rank DIMMs. -- *I'm understanding this as RDIMMs support everything UDIMMs do **plus** quad-rank*
- Single-rank and dual-rank RDIMMs of sizes 2-GB, 4-GB and 8-GB are supported for a total of up to 24 GB. -- *I've got dual-ranked RDIMMs of size 8 GB*
- The memory speed of each channel depends on the memory configuration, for single- or dual-rank memory modules: Two memory modules per channel support up to 1333 MHz. -- *New modules are 1333 Mhz, I've got 2 per channel*

I've tried updating the BIOS to the newest version and trying the new RAM in all possible slot combinations with no luck.

Did I make a mistake in understanding the manual?

Comment: I'm afraid the T310 from 2010 is way out of support.